# attain junior secondary level(s)

Tags: grammaticality

If we want to assess a person's English proficiency, is it idiomatic to say?:

-*His English hasn't attained junior secondary level(s).*

I'm not sure, because:

1. *attain* might not be an idiomatic verb in this situation.
2. instinct tells me *level* should be in the plural but sense tells me a person's English can't attain many levels logically at the same time.
3. the whole sentence might not be idiomatic

Could you help me?

Comment: Is "junior secondary" the recognised name for a particular level/standard of English in your locality? I ask because, to me, "junior secondary" has no meaning and could be contradictory. Also, you may find that [ell.se] is a better forum for asking the type of question.

Answer (score 1):

There is an idiomatic saying similar to this:

> His English is only at a [grade] level.
>
> She can only read at a [grade] level.

[Grade] can be any education level, really, so you would see sentences like this (using American education levels as an example):

> Alice can only read at a 4th grade level.
>
> Bob's English is only at a junior high level.

If "Junior Secondary" is a typical education level in your region than it would be acceptable to say:

> His English hasn't reached junior secondary levels.

If you wanted to use the word "attained" you would use it as such:

> He hasn't attained junior secondary levels in English.

Comment: MrHen, using the words *junior high* or *grade* to refer to education levels is not done in all of the English-speaking world. Doing so depends on context. For example, the UK does not have *junior high* and *grade* means the result achieved in final school exams.

Comment: I added a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *Attain* might not be an idiomatic verb in this situation.

*Attain* is usually used with animate subjects such as humans. I think *reach* would be better.

> Q: Instinct tells me level should be in the plural but sense tells me a person's English can't attain many levels logically at the same time.

It should be singular since as you said you can only reach one level at a time.

And as TrevorD pointed out *junior secondary* might need some elaboration, depending on the audience. Do you mean the lower classes of a secondary school?

Comment: Thanks. Junior Secondary is a lower level than High School. Will this change the idiomatic expression?

Comment: You mean does your sentence become idiomatic if I know that by "junior secondary" you mean "high school"? I would say no.